# App passed null surface error, when startPreview() is called from onCreate

Tags: android

I have been following the [direct camera control tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) from the academy. The camera activates on button press, but when I moved it to a new activity and call it from onCreate, I need to add an onClick listener  for it to activate.

It should be noted, that I am using an AsyncTask to open the camera.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any help is greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this for two days now!

Comment: Post your code and logcat

Comment: ... and the code (at least from onCreate)

Comment: Helpful For u Use This http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly enough, I've been struggling with this error for the last couple of days. Try passing a reference to the AsyncTask constructor and start the preview from there.

The issue, for me at least, was starting the preview, before the camera was open.

Hope this helps!